# German keyboard "Strg + Entspricht" for Expanding code

Tags: intellij-idea, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm just looking at the keymap for the german keyboard on *IntelliJ Ultimate 2016.1*.

For the action `Code -> Folding -> Expand` the shortcut is: <kbd>Strg</kbd>+ <kbd>Entspricht</kbd>

I know that <kbd>Strg</kbd> is the control key but I have no idea what <kbd>Entspricht</kbd> is supposed to mean. Any ideas?

Comment: By the way the meaning of "Entspricht" is "equals" or "stands for"... But as you guys said in the commands below, its probably a bad translation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like it is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>NumPad Plus</kbd>.

[Here](https://resources.jetbrains.com/storage/products/intellij-idea/docs/IntelliJIDEA_ReferenceCard.pdf) is a reference card

Comment: `Ctrl+NumPad +` will also expand the code but it's not the same as `Strg + Entspricht`

Comment: @Roland Why you think so?

Comment: Because when I type the combination `Ctrl+NumPad +` the following appears `Strg+NumPad +` in IntelliJ, so I assume it's not the same thing. Maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: @Roland sorry do not get you

Comment: Is there a key named `Entspricht` on the german keyboard? Either there is or there is a translation error in IntelliJ.

Comment: @Roland I think it is bad translation